# MoPub omits ad networks for being "inactive"

Tags: android, mopub

I set up my interstitial ad on MoPub 4 days ago with 2 different ad networks, but for some reason none of the ad networks get impressions. When I run ad server test on MoPub website i noticed this in log :

```
Removed due to inactivity: Millennial Media key: KEY, MobFox key: KEY
```

MoPub omits my ad networks and takes ads from their marketplace. I generated over 1000 ad requests hoping that it just has to "warm up", but there is no change.

There is also no mention about it in their 'help' section.

Comment: Alice Pang (who appears to be an employee of MoPub Marketplace) has asked you to contact their support via email on `support@mopub.com` with your account and more information on the issue. I am adding this information here in case her non-answer is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution from reddit :

Go to networks>segments>global segment. Remove the filter status:running by clicking on the x to view the greyed out ad networks under your ad by clicking the > arrow next to your ad name. Then enter custom cpms for the networks. They should then turn green and be activated within 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

MoPub has to generate revenue for Twitter and seems to randomly break Mediation Network Integrations in order to make more money from their Marketplace. If you want to use Mediation I'd suggest you join an independent Supply Side Platform.